# Actionscript 3 and StageVideo

Tags: actionscript-3, video, flashdevelop

I'm about to dive into some video programming.  I've done video using Flash CS5, but in this case I'm just using Actionscript 3 and FlashDevelop, so I don't have the Flash CS5 tools.

I've seen a number of references to StageVideo, but I've been working with some of the sample code I've found and, as an example, these lines get an error from the compiler:

```
import flash.media.StageVideo;
import flash.events.StageVideoAvailabilityEvent;
import flash.media.StageVideoAvailability;
```

Has StageVideo gone out of date?  Does FlashDevelop support it?

***Added information:***

This is an AS3 Project.  I get the following errors:

Error: Definition flash.media.StageVideo could not be found

Error: Definition flash.media.StageVideoAvailabilityEvent could not be found

Error: Definition flash.media.StageVideoAvailability could not be found

Comment: Give some information about the error, and try which of them is not importing. `StageVideoAvailability` is not available in AIR, so check which SDK are you using, the AIR of Flex one. Check out target version too!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the **airgobal.swc** to your FD compiler options.

Try this: first find the path to your **airglobal.swc** file. On Windows XP it's probably in

```
 C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5.5\AIR2.6\frameworks\libs\air
```

Something similar in Windows7, but probably under the Program Files(x86) directory. Who knows where-the-hell on a Mac.

Now in your FD menu open `<Project>` then `<Properties>`. Click on the 'Compiler Options' tab. Find the line for 'SWC Include Libraries.' Click on its  '`...`' button and add the path to the **airglobal.swc**. That should be the *complete* path to the file, e.g.:

```
 C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5.5\AIR2.6\frameworks\libs\air\airglobal.swc
```

Your AIR classes should now be found by FD.

Comment: I did that, it didn't make a difference.  I'm in the middle of some other things, will come back and see if I did something wrong.